# Django REST Framework - set filename

Tags: django, view, rendering, django-rest-framework

I have custom renderer(XLSXRender) and its works, but downloaded file has title only "downloaded" without extention. How I can set a filename with file extension?

XLSXRender is in default renderers in `settings.py`, im calling from my app from file `renderers.py`. XLSXRender make from queryset binary file instead of `*.json`. View is classic `viewsets.ModelViewSet`:

```
class CountryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Country.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CountrySerializer
```

Thank you!

Comment: explain your question more clearly. What is XLSXrenderer where is its code what does this class based view do what does it do where are you downloading fie from ?

Comment: @danilke, probably you sholud add [Content-Disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header to your response

Comment: @devxplorer , Thank you, it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Well, same problem currently looking for best solution, this is where I'm now

```
class TileRendered(APIView):
    renderer_classes = (ZipFileRender, )

    def get(self, request):
        table = SampleDbProcedure.all()
        serializer = SampleDbProcedureSerializerTile(table, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, 
                        headers={'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=test_download.zip'})
```

Seems to work better then [this](https://github.com/mjumbewu/django-rest-framework-csv/issues/15)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Django's [FileResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/request-response/#fileresponse-objects):

```py
response = FileResponse(
    excel_file,
    filename="My file name",
    content_type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
)
```